# htaccess redirect to new address removing double quotation and end characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect the url in the form below(including double quotation and backslash!):
`www.isfahancitycenter.com/%22form.php?form=showcalendar&id=168\%22` and its equivalent:
`www.isfahancitycenter.com/"form.php?form=showcalendar&id=168\"`

and also the urls in the form:
`www.isfahancitycenter.com/%5C%22form.php?form=showcalendar&id=168%5C%22`

(where 168 is the parameter that will change) to:

`http://www.isfahancitycenter.com/form.php?form=showcalendar&id=168`

Which means removing double quotation before form.php and any character at the end after the dynamic one 168

any help please?

Comment: Why do you want to fiddle around with the symptom instead of fixing the cause?

Comment: @arkascha well-said! :)